# 2 iAds on simulator

Tags: ios, iad

I am trying to create 2 iAds but I have only one on simulator. I can not now check it with device. Why I have only one? I have only second iAd

My code is:

```
adView1 = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner]; 
adView1.frame = CGRectOffset(adView1.frame, 0, 50);
adView1.delegate = self;
[self.backgroundView addSubview:adView1];

adView2 = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];
adView2.frame = CGRectOffset(adView2.frame, 0, 200);
adView2.delegate = self;
[self.backgroundView addSubview:adView2];


- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
if (!self.bannerIsVisible)

{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
    // banner is invisible now and moved out of the screen on 50 px
            if (banner == adView1)
    {
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, 50);
    }
    if (banner == adView2)
    {
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, 200);
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = YES;
}
}
```

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
  {
  if (self.bannerIsVisible)
  {
      [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
      // banner is visible and we move it out of the screen, due to connection issue
       banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -50);
      [UIView commitAnimations];
      self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
  }
  }

  - (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave
    {
    NSLog(@"Banner view is beginning an ad action");
    BOOL shouldExecuteAction = YES;
    if (!willLeave && shouldExecuteAction)
    {
         [audio pause];
    }
    return shouldExecuteAction;
    }
  - (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner
    {
    [audio resume];
    }

Answer (score 1):

```
adView1.frame = CGRectOffset(adView2.frame, 0, 50);
```

It must be CGRectOffset(adView1.frame, 0, 50); since adView2 is allocation in the next line only???

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating first view, you are using second view's frame:

```
adView1 = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner]; 
adView1.frame = CGRectOffset(adView2.frame, 0, 50);
adView1.delegate = self;
[self.backgroundView addSubview:adView1];
```

As adView2 is not created yet - it is nil and frame is (0,0,0,0)
You have to use adView1 frame for offset as you do for second view.

Also, keep in mind that displaying 2 banners is going against Apple guideline and not recommend. Take a look here (Best practices section)
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/WorkingwithBannerViews/WorkingwithBannerViews.html

Comment: yep, I already fixed it, but first bunner still have no iAd, just rect. If I want use 4 banners and as background (without user interaction) - it will be rejected?

Comment: There is no such restriction in Apple approval policy, your app should not be rejected, but it can cause additional attention to your application and moderators can make some issues regarding iAds. So it is a risk